# axios concurrent requests: any way to get the results from the successful requests even if some have failed?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, request, axios

I'm trying to see how to work with concurrent async requests in javascript, do you know a way with axios of getting the results of the successful requests even if one fails? If not, how would you handle that situation?

```
var axios = require( 'axios' )

var options = [{
      baseURL: 'https://some-base-url'
    , url: '/some-path&key=some-key'
    , method: 'post'
    , data: 'some-data'
}, {
      baseURL: 'https://some-base-url'
    , url: '/some-path&key=some-key'
    , method: 'post'
    , data: 'some-other-data'
}, {
      baseURL: 'https://some-base-url'
    , url: '/some-path&key=WRONG-KEY' // WRONG KEY
    , method: 'post'
    , data: 'some-other-data'
}]

axios.all([
      axios.request(options[ 0 ])
    , axios.request(options[ 1 ])
    , axios.request(options[ 2 ])
]).then(axios.spread(function (res1, res2, res3) {
    // when all requests successful
}))
.catch(function(res) {
    // third request was unsuccessful (403) but no way to get 
    // the results of the two previous successful ones?
    console.log( res )
})
```

Comment: related issue was solved, https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/384

Answer (score 11):

Add a .catch block for the "optional" request

```
axios.all([
      axios.request(options[ 0 ])
    , axios.request(options[ 1 ])
    , axios.request(options[ 2 ]).catch(function() { return false})
]).then(axios.spread(function (res1, res2, res3) {
    console.log(res1) //Respone of options[0]
    console.log(res2) //Response of options[1]
    console.log(res3) //False (When options[2] fails)
}))
```

Comment: if a request is failing with ``404`` then its not coming into the then callback.. its going in catch. how to solve this?

Comment: got the answer. just linking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53064328/axios-how-to-run-http-requests-concurrently-and-get-the-result-of-all-requests/53064769#53064769

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) when you want to keep data from successful requests even if one (or more) of them fails.

```
Promise.allSettled([
    axios.request(options[ 0 ]),
    axios.request(options[ 1 ]),
    axios.request(options[ 2 ]),
]).then(values => {
    console.log(values[0]) // { status: 'fulfilled', value: Respone of options[0]}
    console.log(values[1]) // { status: 'fulfilled', value: Respone of options[1]}
    console.log(values[2]) // { status: 'rejected', reason: Error: an error }
}))
```