# AXIOS: how to run http requests concurrently and get the result of all requests event if a request fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios

I am trying to make server get requests concurrently, in order to do that I have written the following function.

**Problem**

If a single call is failing then I am not able to get the response of rest of the requests.

```
export const getAll = async (collection) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const requests = collection.map(req => {
            const config = {
                headers: req.headers,
                params: req.params
            }
            return axios.get(req.url, config);
        })

        axios.all(requests)
            .then(axios.spread((...args) => {
                // all succerss
                resolve(args);
            }))
            .catch(function (error) {
                // single call fails and all calls are lost
                reject(error)
            });
    })
}
```

Is it possible to get the result of all requests whether it fails or success?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In other words even if request fails you want to act rest of the code like request has succeed.

Let's assume that response cannot be `null`. Then we catch request's error and return `null` in this case for request.

```
export const getAll = async (collection) => {
    const requests = collection.map(req => {
        const config = {
            headers: req.headers,
            params: req.params
        };
        return axios.get(req.url, config).catch(() => null);
    })
    return axios.all(requests);
}
```

So if you have `catch()` and it does not throw exception all later code works like Promise has been resolved not rejected.

Also note you don't need to return `Promise` explicitly from `async` function because it happens automatically. Even more: since you don't have `await` inside the function you actually don't need it to be marked as `async`. And finally `axios.all` returns `Promise` so you don't need to `resolve`/`reject` Promise manually.

Comment: It worked like a charm. I heartily appreciate your answer

Comment: This is the most elegant way I have seen it. It's beautiful.

Comment: very good although they plan on removing it so better use `Promise.all` instead of `axios.all` https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1042

Answer (score 1):

the way I've done this in the past is by wrapping the return value of my promise into an object that either has a `result` field or something similar and an `err` field:

```
export const getAll = async (collection) => {
    const requests = collection.map(req => {
        const config = {
            headers: req.headers,
            params: req.params
        }

        return axios.get(req.url, config)
            //wrap all responses into objects and always resolve
            .then(
                (response) => ({ response }),
                (err) => ({ err })
            );
    });

    return axios.all(requests)
        //note that .then(axios.spread((...args) => {}) is the same as not using
        //spread at all: .then((args) => {})
        .then(axios.spread((...args) => {
            //getAll will resolve with a value of
            //[{ response: {}, err: null }, ...]

            return args;
        }))
        .catch((err) => {
            //this won't be executed unless there's an error in your axios.all
            //.then block

            throw err;
        });
}
```

also see @skyboyer's post for some good points he's made about the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete node js based example based on the Andrew solution:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const getAll = async (collection) => {
    const requests = collection.map(req => {
        const config = {
            // headers: req.headers,
            params: req.params
        }

        return axios.get(req.url, config)
        //wrap all responses into objects and always resolve
            .then(
                (apiResponse) => ({
                    apiResponse
                }),
                (apiError) => ({
                    apiError
                })
            );
    });

    return axios.all(requests)
    //note that .then(axios.spread((...args) => {}) is the same as not using
    //spread at all: .then((args) => {})
        .then(axios.spread((...args) => {
            //getAll will resolve with a value of
            //[{ response: {}, err: null }, ...]

            return args;
        }))
        .catch((axiosError) => {
            //this won't be executed unless there's an error in your axios.all
            //.then block

            throw axiosError;
        });
}

let api1 = {url: "http://localhost:3000/test?id=1001", param: ""};
let api2 = {url: "http://localhost:3000/test?id=1002", param: ""};
let api3 = {url: "http://localhost:3000/test?id=1003", param: ""};
let apis = [api1, api2, api3];

getAll(apis).then((res) => {
        console.log("getAll call finished");
        //console.log(res);
    }
);
```